# Access to Word using Bookmarks, how to perform an action if a bookmark is left blank

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Fairly New to access here and I feel this should be a really simple fix but everything I try isn't working.

Basically what I want to do is make a bog-standard letter generation button for a database I'm working on, and It's working great except where there isn't a field filled in on the Form I'm pulling all the data off of. For example, I have the option for a second address line but not all addresses have one so it's often left blank but that means my addresses come out like this:

Address Line 1

Town
County
PostCode

When I want them to look like this:

Address Line 1
Town
County
PostCode

I've tried everything it seems but nothing seems to be working!

Thanks for any advice or help you can give!!

Here's my code btw

```
Private Sub btnManagerLetter_Click()

    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    
    Set wdApp = New Word.Application
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open("\\middle\Data\DataBaseWordDocs&Ding\ding\InsCoLtrTemplate.docx")
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("qryManagerDetails")
    
    wdApp.Visible = True
    
    wdDoc.Bookmarks("ManagerName").Range.Text = Nz(rs![Manager Name], "")
    
    wdDoc.Bookmarks("AddressLine1").Range.Text = Nz(rs![Address Line 1], "")

    wdDoc.Bookmarks("AddressLine2").Range.Text = Nz(rs![Address Line 2], "")
    
    wdDoc.Bookmarks("Town").Range.Text = Nz(rs![Town], "")
    
    wdDoc.Bookmarks("County").Range.Text = Nz(rs![County], "")
    
    wdDoc.Bookmarks("PostCode").Range.Text = Nz(rs![Post Code], "")
    

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a single bookmark for the address where you paste it as a block.

Using a  helper function to build the address fields, which appends only if the new string is not Null.

For example:

```
Public Function Append(ByVal originalString As String, ByVal newString As String, Optional ByVal separator As String = " ") As String
    If Len(newString) > 0 Then
        AppendString = originalString & separator & newString
    Else
        AppendString = originalString
    End If
End Function
```

---

Then just build the address block and insert it to the bookmark all together as a single string.

```
Sub T()
    
    Dim address As String
    
    address = Nz(rs![Address Line 1], vbNullString)
    address = Append(address, Nz(rs![Address Line 2], vbNullString))
    address = Append(address, Nz(rs![Town], vbNullString))
    address = Append(address, Nz(rs![County], vbNullString))
    address = Append(address, Nz(rs![Post Code], vbNullString))
    
    wdDoc.Bookmarks("Address").Range.Text = address
End Sub
```

You can change the separator to suit you needs, a space `" "` or a new line `vbNewLine`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, not sure where I'm supposed to put a public function, I tried putting it in a module but it's saying that 'address' is an undefined variable.

Comment: The address is a local string variable in `btnManagerLetter_Click()` method which holds the address. The `Append()` method can be private in the same file you have the aforementioned method.

Comment: Ah I see, I had forgotten to add Dim address As String in my sub. now it is saying that the 'AppendString' (Line 3 of  Public Function) is an undefined variable?

Comment: I've just Removed the 'String' so it now reads Append = original string &... and that's done the trick! @KostasK Thank you so much for the Help!!!!